# Adding compression to existing mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to add compression to an existing collection that was created prior to mongodb 3.x? If so, how?

I found an example of how to create a new collection with compression, but I haven't found anything as far as strategies for adding compression to an existing one.
http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30

Answer (score 0):

Version prior to 3.x MongoDB had only one storage engine - `MMAPv1` which **still does not** support compression. With 3.0 MongoDB introduced pluggable storage engines, and one of them - `wiredTiger` storage engine supports compression.

The problem is that you cannot use data files created with one storage engine (say `MMAPv1`) with another one (e.g. `wiredTiger`).

So the only thing you can do is just `mongodump`, initialise `mongod` with `--storageEngine wiredTiger` using another data directory (with `--dbpath`), and then `mongorestore` to your new `mongod` instance.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to compress mongodb collection.

```
1) repair collection using command "mongod --repair"
      or by running command "db.repairDatabase()"
2) using db.runCommand({ compact: <collection name> })
```

Comment: That does not compress a collection